# Is this the correct format to use onclick function inside a ajax request

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call an onclick event. But because of some issue its not working. I'am using following code inside a javascripts file

```
html += "<td>" + mobile + "</td>";
html += "<td><button onclick"+(delid)+">"+delid+"</button> </td>";
```

Comment: For the most part you should be avoiding inline bindings all together, and binding to the elements directly with `$(selector|element).on()` or the native `addEventListener`, or indirectly with a delegate event binding.

Comment: If you `console.log(html);` you should be able to see why it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
html += "<td><button onclick"+(delid)+">"+delid+"</button> </td>";
```

to

```
html += "<td><button class='my-button' data-id='"+ delid +"'>"+ delid +"</button></td>";
```

so it has the id as a data attribute, and then you can use a delegate event handler to process the click of the buttons later.

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.my-button', function(e){
  var id = $(e.target).data('id');

  //do whatever you want
});
```